# How to create a bus topology in Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: networking

How do I create a bus topology in Cisco Packet Tracer?

I've been searching in Google and Cisco's site but cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the devices in the lower left corner select a Hub, assuming that you mean an Ethernet bus.  All devices attached to the hub will be in one collision domain.